# Android app stops when making random number

Tags: java, android

I cant seem to find this answer anywhere. I've tried all the code i could find.
I have an app that needs to make 2 random numbers, which the user will add together. Its a math practicing app.

Here is the xml code for the ui.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/num1"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/oper"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/oper" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/num2"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/oper"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oper"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oper"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/oper"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="72sp" />
```

---

The first textview and the third are random numbers to be generated by the app. The second textview is just an addition sign.

Here is my java code (keep in mind this is not a mainActivity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_addition);
    updateNums();

}

public void updateNums(){
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int randval = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TextView num1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num1);
            num1.setText(randval);
            final TextView num2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num2);
            num2.setText(randval);
        }});
}
```

Comment: An exception is probably being thrown. Can you check your logcat and report back?

Comment: I forgot to mention the problem. i hope you all see this comment. The app stops working and shuts down when ever it reaches the part to set the text  to the number.

Comment: Convert random number to String and then add it to text field

Comment: I did remove the finals and still did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the random-value to a String - otherwise it is treated as a string-res

```
public void updateNums(){
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int randval = random.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final TextView num1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num1);
            num1.setText(String.valueOf(randval));
            final TextView num2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num2);
            num2.setText(String.valueOf(randval));
        }});
}
```

Comment: Wow that worked. Thank you so much! I never thought i would get help this fast!

Comment: @AmirAbbas would be great if you could accept the answer then

Comment: @ligi i wanted to but it said i had to wait until a certain amount of time was over after you submitted the answer and i had to go to school. Thanks :)